# Script tag Issues / Atom editor stop accepting script tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have this two page on my w.i.p. website, and i can't find where is the problem, the code it's exactly the same in the beginning, I've also try download the jQuery files, but nothing change, sorry for the noob question, I know there is similar questions on S.O. but i can't find the right solution.

[image: Code with error]

[image: Code work fine]

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');


     ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
        img.src = "https://svgshare.com/i/LDY.sfsvg," ;



      img.onload = function()  {
         ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, e.clientX, e.clientY,);



     }
  });
  });
```

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #800f62;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.containerL{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
.containerR{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>

    <div class="containerL">
      <h1>Spontaneus</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="containerR">
      <h1>Requested</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: When you open the page in a browser is there actually a difference because this might just be a visual glitch

Comment: Yes, i've add a snippet on the question, the jQuery it's used to do that little mousemove animation (in the snippet works fine), but  opening the html in a browser doesn't work, i think it s for this issue